# Requests giving me error with correct url

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to search an API and when using the requests function I get an error that seems to indicate that there is nothing in JSON on the URL.When putting in my browser it works, and the function works in a similar piece of code.

This is my first ever time trying to code anything, so I getting to here was an effort but now I am just stuck and not sure where my error is. right now I am printing the URL, and when I put into my browser I find JSON code and the code works in another similar program I was making for testing.

```
import requests
import time

api = 'https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/'


f = open('Pokemon.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    url = (api + line)
    print(url)

    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    Result = (json_data)
    print(result)
```

Here I get this back:

```
https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/Bulbasaur

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fierce-PC\Desktop\MC Name project\Pokemon.py", line 12, in <module>
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
  File "C:\Users\Fierce-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Fierce-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Fierce-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Fierce-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>>
```

You can clearly see that https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/Bulbasaur works if you click on it and it is in JSON format and I just don't really understand the problem.

What confused me more is that this code works

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

api = 'https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/'


Name = 'Bulbasaur'

url = (api + Name)
print(url)


json_data = requests.get(url).json()
print(json_data)
```

And it outputs this like I would want but it will not work with in the loop of looking through every Pokemon

```
{'id': '06e299358e2f44f1ad8c5f859d63973b', 'name': 'Bulbasaur'}
```

Sorry if this is a badly constructed post or that I am missing something really obvious.

EDIT: I edited both versions of the code to look like this:

```
    json_data = requests.get(url)
    print(json_data)
```

And for the print on the second line on the version that works I get this back

```
<Response [200]>
```

Where as on my main not working program I get this:

```
<Response [204]>
```

This as far as I can tell indicates that my code is not working though I am not too sure of the fix still though

Comment: You might want to `strip()` the URL before making the request to get rid of the trailing new line.

Comment: i would always do the `request.get()` and validate that it worked by looking at `status_code` before moving on with the json. Assuming that a network request will always work is brave.

Comment: `for line in f.readlines():` to iterate through the lines of a file

Comment: @JacquesGaudin The `for line in f` is perfectly acceptable, and preferable in my opinion, since early python2 days as it increases readability.

Comment: @dwagon Really? Thanks a lot, I didn't know!

Comment: @dwagon Looks like you were right about networking, though I am still unsure of the solution from here.

Comment: Is there an API request limit? Is it always failing at the same point when issuing requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It iterates across the lines in your file, constructs the URL and then tries to get the data; on failure it should print the reason and keep going on the next line.

```
with open('Pokemon.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        url = (api + line.strip())
        print(url)

        conn = requests.get(url)
        if not conn.ok:
            print("Failure on {}: {}".format(url, conn.reason))
            continue
        result = conn.json()
        print(result)
```